# Database protection using functions

Tags: postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

Are functions a good way of protecting a database?

I am developing a website with a Postgresql back end and I wish to protect the database data & schema.

I have created Postgres function for all required interactions so no SQL is required on the front end.

All I want a user to be able to see are the functions and be able to execute them.

Answer (score 1):

> Are functions a good way of protecting a database?

A simple question without a simple answer.

- If you want portability: no. It will complicate portability to other Databases
- A lot of modern applications use just CRUD operations: (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete)
- Yes, functions can add a secure layer to protect data and hide complexity.

My suggestion for this way: use a separate schema for functions and grant execution on that schema:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA myschema TO myuser;
```

Comment: Functions are by default executable by everybody anyway. Apart from the permissions question, there is a lot of truth in your answer. "A lot of modern applications use just CRUD operations" to me is the same as saying "a lot of modern applications are poorly written".

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Totally agree...

Comment: so if CRUS apps are poorly written apps then are functions the way to go?

Comment: We can talk about this for days. Every approach as benefits and drawbacks. I, personally, prefer to have a more structured DB.